# How to add secondary patition on sd card to internal memory?

Tags: rooting, partitions, link2sd

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 which I have rooted. I have partitioned my 8GB class 10 SD card to have two partitions on it using AParted:

1. A 2GB FAT32 secondary partition.
2. The rest of the SD card into a primary partition.(FAT32)

The problem is, even after doing this and installing Link2SD and changing the install location to external, the apps are still being installed into the internal memory and I get a "low on internal memory" message every time I try installing new apps. When I check the Link2SD app list, many of the apps are showing that they have been already moved to the SD card and my secondary partition on the sd card is still pretty much empty.

What have I missed over here? (Sorry if this is a lame question. I'm new to rooting and stuff)

[image: Link2SD showing apps moved to the SD card][image: Storage Info part1][image: Storage Info part2]

Answer (score 3):

Note: Techicnally you *probably* couled use a FAT32 partition but I've had issues on several devices.

For `Link2SD` you need 2 partitions:

1) **FAT32** this is your file storage, photos, media etc.

2) **EXT3** (Or EXT2 or EXT4, but 3 has always worked for me) partition. This is the part this will be recognised as new 'internal memory'.

[There is a full tutorial on XDA here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2142844) and the keypoints are:

> Next, create an ext2/ext3/ext4 partition (I suggest ext2 cause it works on all roms and kernels). This is where your apps will go. I suggest a value of 512Mb would be big enough.

Personally I use 1024 Mb.

> Open Link2sd. You will be prompted to choose between ext2, ext3, ext4 and FAT32. Select the one you used.
>
> It will say mount script created. Reboot your phone now
>
> Go to `Link2sd > Settings > Check the autolink` (to automatically move apps upon installation)
>
> To check your memory, select “Storage Info”. This will show you the current state of your internal memory, FAT32, and Ext# partition.

Comment: I tried formatting the sd card again to make the above changes. But now, only 1.9GB of the 8GB is showing up in the format menu(exactly the same as the second partition I made on it). Please help.

Comment: Just undo all of it, make the SD Care ONE SINGLE partition, let's say FAT32, ALL of it. Then create your 2 partitions, one FAT32, and one EXT3. Or use a PC app to do the partitioning.

Comment: I tried doing that but now that partition is "unallocated". I'm searching for a way to get it back.

Comment: If you don't know how to partition things, then be very careful with your device, this could brick it. Allocate ALL of it to ONE SINGLE partition, then repartition it after.

Comment: Yeah. I got that figured out. But this still didn't work. I'm sorry. Now I have created 2 partitions a) FAT32 and b)EXT3. But still when I try to download something new it says "not enough space".

Comment: That's good so far, go through the xda link I provided, it will guide you step by step. You need to setup link2sd now again.

Comment: Finally after 3 reinstalls of Link2SD it worked. When I tried the second time Linked2SD crashed and showed up a blank screen. Thank you.

Comment: Oops.. Spoke too soon. The 'low on internal memory' notification came out again.

Answer (score 0):

Use mini tool partition (windows )  or gparted(linux) to create another partition . The file system must be ext4 . Then when u insert it . You will be asked to format. Format the SDCard . Now open link2sd

Comment: Could you provide the link for the programs? How to use any of them to create "another" partition? Please see [answer].

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience .  My mobile does not support the latest version. So i cannot format or  embed links in the answer. You can find the source in google. Thanks for your advice !